# libc6 on debian wheezy and unmet dependencies

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to install some packages that have a chain of dependencies, ending up requiring libc6 and libc6-dev at the bottom.

I have several machines in GCE set up with debian wheezy (fresh installs), and am getting these errors while trying to install libc6-dev:

```
# apt-get install libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38) but 2.17-93ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.13-38)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


# apt-cache policy libc6  
libc6:
  Installed: 2.17-93ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2.17-93ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2.17-93ubuntu4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.13-38 0
        500 http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages

# apt-cache policy libc6-dev
libc6-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.13-38
  Version table:
     2.13-38 0
        500 http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages


# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb     http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com/ wheezy         main
deb-src http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com/ wheezy         main
deb     http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy         main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy         main
deb     http://security.debian.org/   wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/   wheezy/updates main
```

I looked up the libc6-2.17-93ubuntu4 version and it looks like it is for saucy, not wheezy.

Is this due to the custom wheezy kernel that Google is using?

Any tips on how to go about getting these packages installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a fresh wheezy instance and performed a "apt-get install libc6-dev" without issue. I think one of your other packages is contributing to the dependency conflict.

The injected kernel isn't connected to apt-get so it wouldn't cause a dependency installation issue.